# GWT JSNI does not find recently created element

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I want to create a canvas element in my gwt code. Subsequently, I would like to apply a third party javascript library in order to paint on the newly created canvas dom element. So here is the rough idea, of what I'd like to do:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
        Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        canvas.getElement().setId("canvas");
        canvas.setWidth("800px");
        canvas.setHeight("500px");
        canvas.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "black solid 1px");

        RootPanel.get("rootDiv").clear();
        RootPanel.get("rootDiv").add(canvas);

        getCanvas();
```

The above piece of code creates a new canvas element and adds it to my current dom. After having added the new canvas I would like to apply JSNI to get this canvas element.

```
public static native void getCanvas() /*-{
    console.log("Canvas? = " + document.getElementById("canvas"));
}-*/;
```

Now, I would expect that I had found this canvas element. However, instead I am getting the following output on the console:

```
Canvas? = null
```

Why am I not able to access my new element?

BTW: When I check the DOM in the inspector of Chrome I can see the added canvas element with the assigned id.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
public static native void getCanvas() /*-{
    console.log("Canvas? = " + $wnd.document.getElementById("canvas"));
}-*/;
```

Add `$wnd` before `document`.

And consider using JsInterop instead of JSNI.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. Regarding JsInterop: I do not see how I should apply it in my case. At least I do not understand the documentation or the benefits of JsInterop. Neither the recommended tutorial by this luigi guy. I mean, I want to access the functionality of a 3rd party library.

Comment: In your case, elemental2 already has the two calls you are making, console.log and document.getElementById. Writing JSNI to call a third part library is just as hard as writing JsInterop to call into it, except the JSNI is going to stop working in gwt 3, and isn't type safe like the JsInterop would be.